# swig c library and ctypes uint8 invalid type

Tags: python, c, swig, ctypes, typemaps

I'm using swig to generate my C library, for example:

mylib.py and _mylib.pyd

```
int func(uint8_t* a)
{
    return *a;
}
```

in python:

```
import mylib
import ctypes
a = (ctypes.c_uint8 * 8)()
mylib.func(a)
```

But running the Python gives me an error: `TypeError: in method 'func', argument 1 of type 'uint8 *'`

I search the typemaps, and I add it to my .i module file, like this:

```
%module mylib
%include "typemaps.i"
extern int func(uint8_t* INPUT);
```

python error to be.

I print ctypes.c_uint8 and print mylib uint8, and I found  mylib uint8 is swig object. How to do this work?

Comment: The types from `ctypes` are not compatible with `SWIG` like you try to use them. They are different types. I suggest that you include `%include "carrays.i" and %array_class(unsigner char, uint8ArrayClass)` to your `SWIG` interface file and use the generated `uint8ArrayClass(4)` to generate a wrapped C array for input for e.g. a length 4 array.

Comment: hi  thank u， could u show me a simple text？

Comment: Look in the swig manual search for the keywords I have provided

Answer (score 1):

I think this is fully described in the documentation, but here goes

test.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
int func(uint8_t* a, const size_t len);
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

#include <iostream>

int func(uint8_t* a, const size_t len) {
  int result = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
    result += int(a[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

test.i

```
%module example
%{
  #include "test.h"
%}

%include "carrays.i"
%include "stdint.i"
%array_functions(uint8_t, uint8Array);

%include "test.h"
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name="example",
      py_modules=['example'],
      ext_modules=[Extension("_example",
                     ["test.i","test.cpp"],
                     swig_opts=['-c++'],
    extra_compile_args=['--std=c++11']
                  )]

)
```

Build using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` and test using

```
import example
g = example.new_uint8Array(3)
example.func(g,3)
```